# android room livedata list only returns one entry instead of more entries

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, generated-code

I've got a very mysterious issue when I try to query through a handful of tables and extract a list of data out of it.

**What happens**

I have a query, which should return a set of data grouped by the date. In my case, I have query for a time range of 14 days. This means the query should return 14 entries. What the Room framework realy returns is 1 entry.

**How I tested it so far**

For my test, I created the tables like the Room framework would do for me.

```
CREATE TABLE app_usage (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    app_name VARCHAR(50),
    times LONG,
    usage_time_in_seconds INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO app_usage VALUES (0, 'WhatsApp', DATETIME('now'), 17);
INSERT INTO app_usage VALUES (1, 'WhatsApp', DATETIME('now', '+1 day'), 47);
INSERT INTO app_usage VALUES (2, 'WhatsApp', DATETIME('now', '+2 day'), 34);
INSERT INTO app_usage VALUES (3, 'WhatsApp', DATETIME('now', '+3 day'), 65);
INSERT INTO app_usage VALUES (4, 'WhatsApp', DATETIME('now', '+4 day'), 47);
INSERT INTO app_usage VALUES (5, 'WhatsApp', DATETIME('now', '+5 day'), 7);
INSERT INTO app_usage VALUES (6, 'WhatsApp', DATETIME('now', '+6 day'), 92);

CREATE TABLE emotion (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    times LONG,
    value INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO emotion VALUES (0, DATETIME('now'), 2);
INSERT INTO emotion VALUES (1, DATETIME('now', '+1 day'), 0);
INSERT INTO emotion VALUES (2, DATETIME('now', '+2 day'), 1);
INSERT INTO emotion VALUES (3, DATETIME('now', '+3 day'), 0);
INSERT INTO emotion VALUES (4, DATETIME('now', '+4 day'), 2);
INSERT INTO emotion VALUES (5, DATETIME('now', '+5 day'), 3);
INSERT INTO emotion VALUES (6, DATETIME('now', '+6 day'), 4);

CREATE TABLE step_count (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    times LONG,
    value INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO step_count VALUES (0, DATETIME('now'), 4389);
INSERT INTO step_count VALUES (1, DATETIME('now', '+1 day'), 245);
INSERT INTO step_count VALUES (2, DATETIME('now', '+2 day'), 685);
INSERT INTO step_count VALUES (3, DATETIME('now', '+3 day'), 965);
INSERT INTO step_count VALUES (4, DATETIME('now', '+4 day'), 984);
INSERT INTO step_count VALUES (5, DATETIME('now', '+5 day'), 12);
```

The following SQL-Query is the same I use in my @Dao class to fetch the data. This query is working (I tested it on [SQLiteOnline](https://sqliteonline.com/#/)).

```
SELECT 
MAX(times) as 'Timestamp', 
SUM(usage_time_in_seconds) AS 'UsageTime', 
(SELECT TOTAL(value) FROM step_count WHERE date(times) = DATE(au.times)) AS 'StepCount', 
(SELECT CASE WHEN AVG(value) IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE AVG(value) END FROM emotion WHERE DATE(times) = DATE(au.times)) AS 'Emotion'
FROM app_usage au 
WHERE times BETWEEN DATETIME('now', '+1 day') AND DATETIME('now', '+4 day')
GROUP BY DATE(times) 
ORDER BY times DESC
```

**The implementation**

My implementation of the Dao class:

```
@Dao
@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
public interface SummaryDao {

    @Query("SELECT MAX(timestamp) as 'mTimestamp', " +
            "TOTAL(usage_time_in_seconds) as 'mAppUsageTime', " +
            "(SELECT TOTAL(step_count) FROM StepCountEntity WHERE date(timestamp) = date(aue.timestamp)) as 'mSteps', " +
            "(SELECT CASE WHEN AVG(value) IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE AVG(value) END FROM EmotionEntity WHERE date(timestamp) = date(aue.timestamp)) as 'mEmotionAvg' " +
            "FROM AppUsageEntity aue " +
            "WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo " +
            "GROUP BY date(timestamp) " +
            "ORDER BY timestamp DESC")
    LiveData<List<SummaryEntity>> getSummaries(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo);
}
```

I've also had a look into the SummaryDao_Impl.java, where the real code happens. My debugging session helped me to find out, that the Cursor is only size 1 - every time this method is called. In addition to that, only the values mTimestamp and mAppUsageTime gain a real value. The other variables stay empty. Which should not happen.

I hope the problem I have is clear to you guy's. Otherwise ask me. I am very pleased for every help.

## Solution

The date was saved as timestamp (long) in the database. This means, that the 'date' function of SQLite can not work with the value directly because it expects seconds instead of milliseconds. Due to this, it is necessary to divide the timestamp with 1000 to convert it into seconds. The 'date' function also needs a format to convert the timestamp to. Therefor I used 'unixepoch'.

```
@Dao
@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
public interface SummaryDao {

    @Query("SELECT MAX(timestamp) as 'mTimestamp', " +
            "TOTAL(usage_time_in_seconds) as 'mAppUsageTime', " +
            "(SELECT TOTAL(step_count) FROM StepCountEntity WHERE date(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch') = date(aue.timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch')) as 'mSteps', " +
            "(SELECT CASE WHEN AVG(value) IS NULL THEN 0.0 ELSE AVG(value) END FROM EmotionEntity WHERE date(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch') = date(aue.timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch')) as 'mEmotionAvg' " +
            "FROM AppUsageEntity aue " +
            "WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo " +
            "GROUP BY date(timestamp/1000, 'unixepoch') " +
            "ORDER BY timestamp DESC")
    LiveData<List<SummaryEntity>> getSummaries(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! One thing I am not seeing, is your DateTime Converter, may help to add that to the question. It may be a date/time problem. Why don’t you try to simplify the query to use something else (temporarily) to see if you get ROOM to return a valid list (albeit not the 14 items you want… but still). That would ensure all the “OTHER” things (room, LiveData, observer, etc.) are ok.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your help. I've found another post, which helps me to find the solution for my issue. I already added it to my post.